# How to make the duration of an animation dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

Let's imagine we have an animation that changes a Rectangle's width from **50 to 150** when user moves the cursor over it and back from **150 to 50** when user moves the cursor away. Let the duration of each animation be **1 second**.

Everything is OK if user moves the cursor over the rectangle, then waits for 1 second for animation to finish, and then moves the cursor away from the rectangle. Two animations take 2 seconds totally and their speed is exactly what we are expecting to be.

But if user moves the cursor away before the first animation (50 -> 150) is finished, the second animation's duration will be 1 second but the speed of it will be very slow. I mean, the second animation will animate the rectangle's width not from **150 to 50** but from let's say **120 to 50** or from **70 to 50** if you take cursor away very fast. But for the same **1 second**!

So what I want to understand is how to make the duration of the "backwards" animation to be **dynamic**. Dynamic based on at what point the first animation was stopped. Or, if I specify `From` and `To` values to 150 and 50, `Duration` to 1 seconds and rectangle width will be 100 – WPF would calculate by itself that animation is 50% done.

I was testing different ways to use animation like Triggers, EventTrigger in style, and VisualStateGroups but no success.

Here is a XAML sample that shows my problem. If you want to see by yourself what I am talking about, move the cursor over the rectangle, wait for 1-2 seconds (first animation is finished) then move the cursor away. After that, move the cursor over the rectangle for like 0.25 seconds and move it away. You will see that the rectangle's width changes very slowly.

```
<Rectangle Width="50"
           Height="100"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Fill="Black">
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                 To="150"
                                 Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```

Also, I would like to explain what calculation I am expecting to see.
So let's imagine another animation that goes from **100 to 1100** and has a duration of **2 seconds**. If we stop it at the point of **300**, it must start to go back to **100** but not for 2 seconds but for:

```
((300 - 100) / (1100 - 100)) * 2s = 0.4s
```

If we stop at 900, duration will be:

```
((900 - 100) / (1100 - 100)) * 2s = 1.6s
```

And if we let animation finish normally it will be:

```
((1100 - 100) / (1100 - 100)) * 2s = 2s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF provides the possibility to write custom animations.

You may create one with a `MinSpeed` property:

```
public class MinSpeedDoubleAnimation : DoubleAnimation
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinSpeedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MinSpeed), typeof(double?), typeof(MinSpeedDoubleAnimation));

    public double? MinSpeed
    {
        get { return (double?)GetValue(MinSpeedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinSpeedProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new MinSpeedDoubleAnimation();
    }

    protected override double GetCurrentValueCore(
        double defaultOriginValue, double defaultDestinationValue,
        AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        var destinationValue = To ?? defaultDestinationValue;
        var originValue = From ?? defaultOriginValue;
        var duration = Duration != Duration.Automatic ? Duration :
            animationClock.NaturalDuration;
        var speed = (destinationValue - originValue) / duration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;

        if (MinSpeed.HasValue && Math.Abs(speed) < MinSpeed)
        {
            speed = Math.Sign(speed) * MinSpeed.Value;
        }

        var value = originValue + speed * animationClock.CurrentTime.Value.TotalSeconds;

        return speed > 0 ?
            Math.Min(destinationValue, value) :
            Math.Max(destinationValue, value);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                To="150" Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <local:MinSpeedDoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                To="50" MinSpeed="100"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

---

For completeness here is also the most simple code-behind solution without any Triggers and Storyboards:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="Black" 
           MouseEnter="RectangleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="RectangleMouseLeave"/>
```

with these event handlers:

```
private void RectangleMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(150, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    element.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, animation);
}

private void RectangleMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var duration = (element.ActualWidth - 50) / 100;
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
    element.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, animation);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I think that is what I was looking for, but I have one more question. How can I control the duration of the animation for example in `GetCurrentValueCore` method? So I can calculate for how much more time animation will be active. Because you explained how to make animation **move** right, but not how to correct duration time so it can be finished correctly not only visually but also change its state to done.

Comment: @Yurii Then probably check my other answer.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that you can override `GetNaturalDurationCore` method and calculate duration by yourself. The only problem left is that you need to use something more efficient that `Binding` to the `ActualWidth` property. But it is not that important. At this point, thank you very very much, @Clemens! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Yurii I would like to edit that into the answer. How are you determining the origin and destination values in GetNaturalDurationCore in order to calculate the duration?

Comment: This solution works great! I found one problem: when the animation is sped up and the destination value is reached before the Duration ended, the animations will still be active (until the Duration ends) and the target property will be locked, blocking other animation (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Storyboards are compiled code, meaning you can't use binding in the elements to improve their abilities.

I've had to do something similar and the only way I found to achieve it was to access the storyboard property that needed to be dynamic at the time that I needed to touch it, and set the property as needed in code behind.

So it's not ideal to have to touch and trigger from code behind, but hey look at it this way, it's not business logic, it's strictly presentation layer so code behind is typically acceptable practice.

So handle your trigger in code behind, calculate your numbers, update the storyboard properties and then start it. That's probably going to be your best option for now.

I would love to see storyboards become part of the logical tree with dependency properties to dynamically modify values, so maybe request the feature :).

Comment: Not exactly sure why you are referring to Storyboards when the question is about animations. Anyway, the relevant properties of a DoubleAnimation (To, From, By, …) are actually dependency properties.

Comment: Clemens, a Storyboard is used to perform an animation, my apologies, I assumed you knew that. Right now you nested your storyboard inside a trigger, but you can create a storyboard at the top of your xaml file as well and trigger it differently. Let me know if you have further questions. Also, I would appreciate if you don't down vote when I took the time to offer you a suggestion.

Comment: Also not sure why you think you offered *me* a suggestion. I know all this, and I did not ask the question.

Comment: If you knew all of this, you wouldn't be asking the question lol. But hey best of luck with your poor attitude, I'm sure it will help you get all sorts of help.

Comment: Don't need any help. See my answer (and please try to realize that I am not the one that asked the question here). For *your* information, you don't need to wait to "*see storyboards become part of the logical tree with dependency properties to dynamically modify values*". They already are and as I told you before, there are already dependency properties that you can of course "*modify dynamically*".

Comment: well regardless if you asked the question you are off base here. The "To" and "From" are not part of the logical tree and can not be bound in typical MVVM ways. So if you are hoping to dynamically change these behaviors or similar you will have to do it in code. If you were doing less trolling and actually read the question you would see that he was trying to dynamically handle the "To" and Duration properties between "50 and 150" as well as dynamic timing. These are not items you can put in the XAML bound to custom properties. Otherwise, you would have provided a xaml answer, and you did not.

Comment: lol, I have a project right now with a team of 8 WPF engineers all of which arrived at the same conclusion that the To property didn't work in binding dynamically changing it's value. I am not pulling this out of thin air buddy. At any rate, don't you have anything better to do. I am done replying to your trolling on my response.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a custom animation could be an attached property that is bound to the target element's `ActualWidth`, which dynamically adjusts the animation's `Duration`.

The attached property could look like this:

```
public static class AnimationEx
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicDurationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DynamicDuration", typeof(double), typeof(AnimationEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(DynamicDurationPropertyChanged));

    public static double GetDynamicDuration(DoubleAnimation animation)
    {
        return (double)animation.GetValue(DynamicDurationProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDynamicDuration(DoubleAnimation animation, double value)
    {
        animation.SetValue(DynamicDurationProperty, value);
    }

    private static void DynamicDurationPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var animation = o as DoubleAnimation;
        if (animation != null && animation.To.HasValue)
        {
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
                Math.Abs((double)e.NewValue - animation.To.Value) / 100);
        }
    }
}
```

where there might be another attached property for the speed factor, which is hardcoded as `100` above.

The property would be used like this:

```
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                 To="150" Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="50"
                    local:AnimationEx.DynamicDuration="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Rectangle}}" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```

A possible drawback might be the fact that the Duration is constantly reset when the ActualWidth changes. However, I could not notify any visual effect.